# Nonlinear first oder ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following nonlinear ODE
$$
y'-\frac{y}{x} + \frac{3}{y}\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right) + 1 =0
.
$$

I wasn't able to find any solution. And mathematica didn't solve it either...

Comment: Probably a typo !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici which typo? You mean +1 term? This is correct anyway...

Comment: In such a case stay with an integrating factor

Comment: If Mathematica could not solve it, then that is because it cannot be solved analytically. There are no closed form solutions for this equation. This is a Chini equation, and chini equations generally have no closed form solutions.

Comment: @Angel Thanks for the info. I realized that this is a Chini equation and I transformed it to other ODEs. But I couldn't manage to prove that it has no closed form solution...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the homogeneous equation
$$y'-\frac{y}{x} + \frac{3}{y}\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right)  =0$$ which does not present any problem. Let $y=\sqrt z$ which gives
$$\frac{x \left(z'-6 x+3\right)-2 z}{2 x \sqrt{z}}=0\implies z=C x^2+6 x^2 \log (x)+3 x$$ Back to $y$ and including the $1$ and the variation of parameters, we end with
$$\frac {x^2 C'}{\sqrt{C x^2+6 x^2 \log (x)+3 x}}+2=0$$ which is obviously more than problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the equation by $y$ ($y \ne 0$), one obtains

$$
yy'-\frac{y^2}{x} = 3x-\frac{3}{2}.
$$

Now, let $z = y^2 \Leftrightarrow z' = 2yy' \left(yy' = \frac{z'}{2}\right)$. Then, we have the equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left.\frac{z'}{2}-\frac{z}{x} = 3x-\frac{3}{2}\right|\cdot 2\\
&z'- \frac{2}{x}z = 6x-3,
\end{aligned}
$$

which is a first-order linear differential equation.

Let $z(x) = u(x)v(x)$. Then, $z'(x) = u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x)$.By substituting $z(x)$ and $z'(x)$ into equation, we obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
u'v + uv' - \frac{2}{x}uv &= 6x-3 \\
u'v + u\left(v' - \frac{2}{x}v\right) &= 6x-3
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $v' - \frac{2}{x}v = 0$. Then, $u'v = 6x-3$.

$$
v' - \frac{2}{x}v = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{v'}{v} = \frac{2}{x}\Leftrightarrow \int\frac{v'}{v}dx = \int\frac{2}{x}dx \Leftrightarrow \ln(v) = 2\ln(x) = \ln(x^2) \Leftrightarrow v = x^2
$$

$$
u'v = 6x-3 \Leftrightarrow u' = \frac{6x-3}{v}= \frac{6x-3}{x^2} = \frac{6}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2} \Leftrightarrow u = \int\left(\frac{6}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2}\right)dx = 6\ln|x|+\frac{3}{x}+C
$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
z &= uv = \left(6\ln|x| + \frac{3}{x} + C\right)x^2 \Rightarrow \\
y &= \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{\left(6\ln|x| + \frac{3}{x} + C\right)x^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is a nice solution, but not to my ODE! You forgot the +1 term...

Comment: @Immanuel what a bad typo! you spent time of others.

Comment: @BlackMild ??? They thought that I had a typo. What do you mean? The ODE without +1 term is not that difficult.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice the +1 term :(

Comment: @Eugene No worries! That was a nice solution though...

Answer (score 0):

Let $$z(x)=\frac1{y(x)},$$ so $$y'(x)=-\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)^2},$$ hence $$-\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)^2}-\frac1{xz(x)}+3z(x)\left(\frac12-x\right)+1=0,$$ so $$z'(x)+\frac{z(x)}{x}+3z(x)^3\left(x-\frac12\right)-z(x)^2=0,$$ which can be further rewritten as $$z'(x)=3\left(\frac12-x\right)z(x)^3+z(x)^2-\frac1{x}z(x),$$ which is an Abel equation.